# plist using model class in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, plist

i am making a clickable collection view to navigate next view controller but no array pass to collectionview cell but compiler read it.i want help about plist using model class in collection view.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NokiaList", ofType: "plist"){
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
            print(dict)
            self.arrproducts = NSMutableArray(array: dict.value(forKey: "arrproducts") as! NSArray)
        }
        let product = ProductsDetails()
        let dict = self.arrproducts.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
        product.Name = dict.value(forKey: "Name") as! String
        product.Image = dict.value(forKey: "Image") as! String
        product.Status = dict.value(forKey: "Status") as! String!
        let arr = NSMutableArray()
        arr.add(product)
        let productNew = arr.object(at: 0) as! ProductsDetails
        productNew.Status = "yes"
        arr.removeObject(at: 0)
        arr.insert(productNew, at: 0)
        self.CollectionViewOutlet.reloadData()
    }
```

}

Comment: what you want your question is not clear.

Comment: Do not use `NS(Mutable)Dictionary / Array...` in Swift. Use Swift native types. And don't use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you need KVC. Use key subscription or `objectForKey`. And what is that `add`, `remove`, `insert` dance for? I recommend to use `PropertyListDecoder` to decode the property list directly in the struct.

Comment: that is a part of my code but on build time collection view cell don't get any entry from plist

Comment: `arrproducts` contains an array of dictionaries. The array `arr` exists only locally in the scope of `viewDidLoad` and will contain only one item. You need to map the array of dictionaries to an array of `ProductsDetails`. But once again, use Swift native static types.

Comment: ok i try in this way